# Kde desktop vnc issues

Tags: linux, vnc, kde

I run arch on my server with a kde plasma desktop. With no monitor connected, I get just a black screen on realvnc. Sometimes previously opened windows are visible but closing them reveals a black screen rendering the server useless until the next reboot. The current fix is having a hdmi to vga adapter always plugged in. Surely it can be done better than this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can't edit; the question is: How to remove dongle while retaining kde?

Comment: It's either a dongle or creating a dummy output. The former is far easier.

Comment: @ChanganAuto how would i go about creating the dummy output?